# TypeError: ('__init__() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)', <class 'googleapiclient.errors.HttpError'>, ())

Tags: python, google-analytics-api, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

I was getting data from GA API using python. This is my code:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Hello Analytics Reporting API V4."""

import argparse
import pandas as pd
import time

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

import httplib2
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import file
from oauth2client import tools
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial


SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
DISCOVERY_URI = ('https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest')
KEY_FILE_LOCATION = '/Users/mac/Documents/python-f/client_secrets.p12'
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'mac-test3@prime-imagery-150409.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
VIEW_ID = '108573919'
FILE_NAME = '/Users/mac/Documents/python-f/12ios_bbs_user.csv'
DATE_RANGE = pd.date_range('1/1/2016','12/11/2016')
FILTERS = 'ga:screenName=~论坛'
SEGMENTS_ID = 'gaid::gKXoOymDSxKWjmKVPpPsbA'


def initialize_analyticsreporting():
  """Initializes an analyticsreporting service object.

  Returns:
    analytics an authorized analyticsreporting service object.
  """

  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, KEY_FILE_LOCATION, scopes=SCOPES)

  http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

  # Build the service object.
  analytics = build('analytics', 'v4', http=http, discoveryServiceUrl=DISCOVERY_URI)

  return analytics


def get_report(q_date):
  # Use the Analytics Service Object to query the Analytics Reporting API V4.
  analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
  return analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': [
        {
          'viewId': VIEW_ID,
          'dateRanges': [{'startDate': q_date, 'endDate': q_date}],
          'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:screenviews'},{'expression': 'ga:users'}],
          'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:date'},{'name': 'ga:segment'}],
          #'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:date'}]
          'filtersExpression': FILTERS
          #'segments':  [{'segmentId': SEGMENTS_ID}]
        }]
      }
  ).execute()


def print_response(response):
  content=[]
  for report in response.get('reports', []):
    columnHeader = report.get('columnHeader', {})
    dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get('dimensions', [])
    metricHeaders = columnHeader.get('metricHeader', {}).get('metricHeaderEntries', [])
    rows = report.get('data', {}).get('rows', [])
    hed_r = []
    con_r = []

    mer_h = []
    for m in metricHeaders:
      mer_h.append(m.get('name'))

    hed_r = dimensionHeaders + mer_h

    con_r.append(hed_r)

    for row in rows:
      dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
      dateRangeValues = row.get('metrics', [])
      line=[]
      for di in dimensions:
        line.append(di)
      for values in dateRangeValues:
        for value in values.get('values'):
          line.append(value)
      con_r.append(line)
    content.append(con_r)
  df = DataFrame(content[0])
  df.columns = df.ix[0]

  return df[1:]


def main():

 #analytics1 = initialize_analyticsreporting()
 #startTime = time.time()
  results = []
  date_range = []

  for t in DATE_RANGE:
    date_range.append(t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

  pool = Pool()
  rrr=pool.map(get_report, date_range)
  pool.close()
  pool.join()

  for rlt in rrr:
    rlt = print_response(rlt)
    results.append(rlt)

  results = pd.concat(results, ignore_index=True)
 #endTime = time.time()
  results.to_csv(FILE_NAME,encoding='utf-8')




  '''
  for i, t in enumerate(DATE_RANGE):
    rlt = get_report(analytics, t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    rlt_r = print_response(rlt)
    if i==0:
      results = rlt_r
    else:
      results = pd.concat([results, rlt_r])

    results.index = range(len(results))
    results.to_csv(FILE_NAME,encoding='utf-8')
'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

The first time I runed it, it succeed. But the second time, there is some error, looks like it's about multithread. error message:

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mac/.edm/envs/edm/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/mac/.edm/envs/edm/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/Users/mac/.edm/envs/edm/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 389, in _handle_results
    task = get()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: ('__init__() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)', <class 'googleapiclient.errors.HttpError'>, ())
```

how can I solve it?

Comment: First you need to figure out which method requires 3 arguments for which you are only sending one.

Comment: Could you tell me how to find it, the error message didn't say about it

Comment: Thank you I will try to debugging it.:)